# What would be a good particle point-of-view model of a self-gravitating molecular cloud: with orbit or not?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics

Excuse my poor English, I have a lot to learn.

Should we imagine a particle falling directly to the center without an orbit like an apple falling from a tree to Earth, converting its potential energy into kinetic energy or a particle orbiting the center, like a planet around a star, an orbit that decreases as the particle converts its potential energy into kinetic energy. Also, what comes before, cloud collapse or thermal radiation release, i.e. cloud collapse that causes thermal radiation to be released or thermal radiation release that causes the cloud collapse? If I want to do calculations, do I have to put all the mass of the cloud in the center?

**Does the particle, when it emits thermal radiation, immediately lose kinetic energy to regain more as it converts its potential energy or does its kinetic energy only increase in the process, i.e. there is no momentary drop in kinetic energy.**

I watched a video on the subject - a link that directs to the video in question is quoted at the bottom of the details - and it wasn't clear.

https://youtu.be/ULYK_9NwN28

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216629/123208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to think about the particles in a gas cloud being in orbit. The particles bump into each other and change their motion frequently. A gas cloud is supported by pressure, not orbital motion. However, if the cloud is systematically rotating that would be an additional source of (centrifugal) support.

In terms of what comes first, radiation or contraction - it is radiation that causes contraction. If the gas cloud has a temperature it will radiate, whatever its state of (dis)equilibrium.

*If* the gas cloud is spherically symmetric then you can assume that a particle is under the gravitational influence only of the mass interior to its radius, and that mass can be considered to be placed at the centre.

Comment: « Now let's take the case of a gravitating cloud, before fusion is ignited. we model the system as a point mass with lumps of matter in orbit around it. If we attach rocket motors to those lumps to speed them up a bit, they shift out to orbits of greater diameter and while doing so, they slow down since it takes less speed to maintain orbit farther out from the gravitating central mass. So, by adding energy to the system, it cools down (that is, it moves more slowly). » Niels Nielsen

Comment: niels nielsen (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/40292/niels-nielsen), How do you explain the statement - "as heat flows from the core of a star outwards, said core heats up and the shell cools down"?, URL (version: 2022-11-04): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/735246

Comment: He is wrong? Or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: The more I learn about it, the more I realize that the information contradicts each other.

Comment: « In my opinion that "collapsing nebula" image is somewhat misleading, because the trajectory of dust/gas particles would be (ignoring magnetic field) an orbit and not a free fall collapse. However collisions make particle change orbit, and the particles whose new orbits comes closer to the future sun experience more collisions (because of the higher density there) and eventually end up within the sun. ». 
Nicolas https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82805

Comment: @Priscilla do you think the molecules in the Earth's atmosphere are in orbit around the Earth?

Comment: Good point.  I will get a reference on the matter hoping to be able to put an end to my questioning. By the way, would you have any ideas for books on star formation to suggest to me? Preferably a book that doesn't require a master's or doctoral degree on the subject and whenever possible doesn't require the reader to do math beyond differential equations?

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/Stars-Stellar-Processes-Mike-Guidry/dp/1107197880/ref=asc_df_1107197880_nodl?tag=googlemobshop-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=341773020850&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=610965861149305432&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1002517&hvtargid=pla-699367309367&psc=1&dplnkId=05f02636-c3d2-45ee-938b-4d7622836d48

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Star-Formation-Derek-Ward-Thompson/dp/0521630304/ref=nodl_?dplnkId=44cfa007-2574-4e05-996f-2d45c9e5ec6a

Comment: I hesitate beween both.